# Attribute error: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, statsmodels, summary

I am trying to get summary in Backward-elimination method of Multiple linear regression and getting the error.

Here is the code in which I am getting error.

```
X_opt = X[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5]]
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=Y, exog=X_opt).fit
regressor_OLS.summary()
```

```
AttributeError     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-c8a038cdb955> in <module>
----> 1 regressor_OLS.summary()

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

It should simply return the table of regressor but it is showing error.

Comment: What's `sm.OLS(endog=Y, exog=X_opt).fit`?

Comment: Change `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=Y, exog=X_opt).fit` to `regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=Y, exog=X_opt).fit()` since `fit()` is a method.

Comment: @YilunZhang Thanks a lot. It solved the issue. How silly of me. **I forgot to do parentheses**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by two different ways:

```
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=Y, exog=X_opt)
results = regressor_OLS.fit()
```

or:

```
regressor_OLS = sm.OLS(endog=Y, exog=X_opt).fit()
```

I hope helped you :)